# Saving fetched JSON into variable

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I'm trying to get JSON saved into a variable, but it seems I don't understand everything here. I get JSON show up in console a once the way I like, but after I try to call it again later it only returns promise. How can I get JSON saved into a variable, so I could use objects in JSON later?

```
var jsondata = fetch(url).then(
    function(u){ return u.json();}
  ).then(
    function(json){
      console.log(json);
    }
  )
console.log(jsondata);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
let jsondata;    
fetch(url).then(
        function(u){ return u.json();}
      ).then(
        function(json){
          jsondata = json;
        }
      )
```

Basically you need to assign your `jsondata` variable once the promise resolves with the actual data. Currently, you're assigning the entire promise to your `jsondata` variable which is not what you want.

Comment: technically this is possible, and correct/working code. But I'd highly discourage this approach. Because now you have to implement/duplicate the same state-management that the Promises already provide you just to know when `jsondata` is filled and it is safe to use that value.

Comment: this is a horrible answer. if you print jsondata outside of fetch, it will be "undefined".

Answer (score 29):

The fetch API is Promise based and will always return a new Promise either resolved or rejected. You have multiple options to return the result.

#### Async/Await

```js
async function getData(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);

  return response.json();
}

const data = await getData(url);

console.log({ data })
```

#### Callback

```js
function getData(url, cb) {
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => cb(result));
}

getData(url, (data) => console.log({ data }))
```

Comment: `.then(result => result)` is pointless. And `const result = await response.json(); return result` is pretty much the same thing. You can simply `return response.json()`

Comment: the Async/Await example causes an error with the message "Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions, async generators and modules"

Comment: @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan Yes, `await` can only be called in an `async` function. Except in some newer versions of Node.js that support top-level await: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate function outside the fetch function to deal with json data like in below code the fetch function is passing the complete json object to another function called "data_function" we can proceed and work with JSON object in through this "data_function".

```
//fetch function
fetch(url).then(
function(u){ return u.json();}
).then(
function(json){
data_function(json); //calling and passing json to another function data_function
}
)

//another functions
function data_function(data){
alert(data.length); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using a callback as a parameter this way you aren't exposing a variable to global scope.

```
function getFromAPI(url, callback){
  var obj;
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => obj = data)
    .then(() => callback(obj))
 }

getFromAPI('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', getData);

function getData(arrOfObjs){
  var results = "";
  arrOfObjs.forEach( (x) => {
    results += "<p> Id: " + x.id + "<ul>"
    Object.keys(x).forEach( (p) => {
        results += "<li>" + (p + ": " + x[p]) + "</li>";
    });
    results += "</ul> </p> <hr>"
  })
  results += "";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = results;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5gch2yzw/

Answer (score 0):

You can create another async function, `getData()`, in this example, and add the data from the fetched URL to the global variable.

When the `getData()` function is called, it fetches the city data from the provided URL asynchronously using the `fetchData()` function. Once the data is successfully fetched, it is added to the global variable `citiesData`, and you can use this data in other parts of your code.

```js
async function fetchData(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

const citiesData = [];
const url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Miserlou/c5cd8364bf9b2420bb29/raw/2bf258763cdddd704f8ffd3ea9a3e81d25e2c6f6/cities.json';

// Fetch data only once
async function getData() {
    const data = await fetchData(url);
    citiesData.push(...data);
}

getData();


console.log(citiesData);
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest approach is to use async/await method.

Simply copy & paste the following code in your chrome dev console to see the magic:

```
async function githubUsers() {
            let response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users')
            let users = await response.json()
            console.log(users)
    }

githubUsers()
```